# How do I fill tournament brackets with team names, then make the team names uneditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working on a tournament bracketing system, and I found a library called "JQuery bracket" which can help a lot. But there are some problems:

I was planning to retrieve team names (and possibly match scores) from a PostgreSQL database and put them on the brackets. However, the data must be in JSON, and the parser is in Javascript. I can't seem to figure out a workaround.

Original code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Bracket editor</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.json-2.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.bracket.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.bracket.min.css" />
<style type="text/css">
.empty {
  background-color: #FCC;
}
.invalid {
  background-color: #FC6;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function newFields() {
  return 'Bracket name [a-z0-9_] <input type="text" id="bracketId" class="empty" /><input type="submit" value="Create" disabled />'
}

function newBracket() {
  $('#editor').empty().bracket({
  save: function(data){
      $('pre').text(jQuery.toJSON(data))
    }
  })
  $('#fields').html(newFields())
}

function refreshSelect(pick) {
  var select = $('#bracketSelect').empty()
  $('<option value="">New bracket</option>').appendTo(select)
  $.getJSON('rest.php?op=list', function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(i, e) {
      select.append('<option value="'+e+'">'+e+'</option>')
    })
  }).success(function() {
    if (pick) {
      select.find(':selected').removeAttr('seleceted')
      select.find('option[value="'+pick+'"]').attr('selected','selected')
      select.change()
    }
  })
}

function hash() {
  var bracket = null
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/#!([a-z0-9_]+)$/gi, function(m, match) {
    bracket = match
  });
 return bracket;
}

$(document).ready(newBracket)
$(document).ready(function() {
    newBracket()
    $('input#bracketId').live('keyup', function() {
      var input = $(this)
      var submit = $('input[value="Create"]')
      if (input.val().length === 0) {
        input.removeClass('invalid')
        input.addClass('empty')
        submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled')
      }
  else if (input.val().match(/[^0-9a-z_]+/)) {
    input.addClass('invalid')
    submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled')
  }
  else {
    input.removeClass('empty invalid')
    submit.removeAttr('disabled')
  }
})

$('input[value="Create"]').live('click', function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')
  var input = $('input#bracketId')
  var bracketId = input.val()

  if (bracketId.match(/[^0-9a-z_]+/))
    return

  var data = $('#editor').bracket('data')
  var json = jQuery.toJSON(data)
  $.getJSON('rest.php?op=set&id='+bracketId+'&data='+json)
    .success(function() {
      refreshSelect(bracketId)
    })
})

refreshSelect(hash())

$('#bracketSelect').change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val()
  location.hash = '#!'+value
  if (!value) {
    newBracket()
    return
  }
  $('#fields').empty()

  $.getJSON('rest.php?op=get&id='+value, function(data) {
    $('#editor').empty().bracket({
        init: data,
        save: function(data){
            var json = jQuery.toJSON(data)
            $('pre').text(jQuery.toJSON(data))
            $.getJSON('rest.php?op=set&id='+value+'&data='+json)
          }
      })
      }).error(function() { })
    })
  })
</script>
</head>
<body>
Pick bracket: <select id="bracketSelect"></select>
<div id="main">
<h1>jQuery Bracket editor</h1>
<div id="editor"></div>
<div style="clear: both;" id="fields"></div>
<pre></pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the data is retrieved, upon display, you are going to want to add `disabled` to the html input element. For instance:

```
<input type="text" id="bracketId" class="empty" disabled>
```

This will render your text field uneditable.

If you are looking to do this as people are filling out their brackets, I would suggest you either add a `<button>` after each bracket or fire a jquery event with the `mouseout()` listener that adds the `disabled` attribute to your input fields.